# How to pass variables into Bookshelf function?

Tags: javascript, database, phantomjs, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am creating a web app and am using bookshelf to query one of my databases. However, I want to get some information from my database and put it into an array, but I don't know how to pass the array into my `then` function. How do I do this?

Here is my current code:

```
var courses = [];
Bookshelf.knex('users').where('email', req.session.user.email).then(function(users) {
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        courses.push(user);
    });
});
console.log(courses);
```

When I try to do this, nothing gets put into courses. Could anyone tell me how to allow the bookshelf call to access the courses variable?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0):

since this involves async operation you can't get the result in sync fashion. You should be doing something like this

```
var courses = [];
Bookshelf.knex('users').where('email', req.session.user.email).then(function(users) {
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        courses.push(user);
    });
}).then(() => console.log(courses));
```